# Why does my regression neural network completely fail to predict some points?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, neural-networks, optimization, algorithms

I would like to train a NN in order to approximate an unknown function $y = f(x_1,x_2)$. I have a lot of measurements $y = [y_1,\dots,y_K]$ (with K that could be in the range of 10-100 thousands) which come out from either a simulation or a measurement of a system. I've built a feed-forward NN for solving this problem by using a MSE loss-function, i.e.

$$\mathcal{L} = \frac{1}{K}\sum_{i=1}^K(y_i-\hat{y}_i)^2$$

where I defined as $\hat{y}$ the prediction of the NN. As per activation function I used a *ReLU*. The network topology is fairly simple with *input layer* having two neurons $(x_1,x_2)$, three *hidden layers* with 10 neurons each and finally the *output layer* (single output neuron).

After the training process expires I've obtained a very curious result. The loss function assumes very small values hence (apparently) indicating that the training is successful. However, if I analyse the squared-error point-by-point, i.e. the quantity

$$ \boldsymbol{\epsilon}_y = [(y_1-\hat{y}_1)^2,\dots,(y_K-\hat{y}_K)^2] $$
I find that for the vast majority of points said quantity is basically zero, with exception of some "outliers" where the error is huge. It looks like this event happens where the gradient of $f()$ is rather big, which might be a reasonable assumption maybe.

I would like for this to not happen anymore. I'd rather accept a slightly bigger error throughout the whole function domain then have the majority of points with null error but some local points that are completely off. As a requirement, the network topology shall be kept rather "easy" so I would not like to increase the number of layers and/or neurons per layer. As a side node, I've also tried to increase the topology complexity a little bit (i.e. 15 neurons per hidden layer and adding a 4th hidden layer) obtaining slighlty better results but still unacceptable error around the steepest points of the function.

I've got two ideas for now:

1. Use a different loss-function $\mathcal{L}$
2. Sample the dataset $(x_1,x_2)$ more frequently around steepest regions, and less frequently where the function is rather smooth and flat

#### First option

A different loss-function to be adopted. I'm not very familiar with loss-function that might help solve my problem, some rather quick research yielded no good results and I found no significant literature highlighting this kind of problem. I initially thought of something of the likes of

$$ \mathcal{L} = \frac{1}{K}\sum_{i=1}^K(y_i-\hat{y}_i)^2 + \mu\, max\{\boldsymbol{\epsilon}_y\} $$
where $\mu$ is some tuned parameter that penalizes the maximum error. I'm not sure if this makes sense and if it increases the training complexity to the extent that the training process runs in no convergence territory.

#### Second option

I am not sure how to formalize the undersampling where the function is smooth and flat, I imagine that some kernel used for image processing (edge detection kind of kernels of some sort?) might be helpful but I'm in completely unknown territory.

#### Conclusion

I'm looking for some insight and ideas (literature results or analogous cases linked are a huge plus!) for solving this curious problems.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: You should be able to achieve your goal of a slightly larger error throughout if you add weight decay (L2 penalty); this gives you a knob that you can turn to "dial in" the desired [tag:regularization] strength to your taste.

Comment: Could you use the proper name instead of an acronym? NN could be as well nearest-neighbors.

Comment: *"The loss function assumes very small values indicating that the training is successful"* - more likely it is indicating that you are overfitting. The first thing to do is compare the errors on a training and test sets